# Question about the Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, pi, transcendental-numbers, constants

- My question is fairly simple: I was wondering if
  $\,\,\,\Gamma\left(\pi\right) = 2.2880377\ldots\,\,\,$ had any special meaning.
- Is it irrational ?. transcendental ? is it useless ? does it have a name ?.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function rather suggests that rational arguments are of particular interest

Comment: Simple questions not always have simple answers. I think, that it will be extremely difficult to show that the number is irrational, let alone to show that it is transcendental. Numerical analysis indicates that it is transcendental.